# Is my angularjs application development in the correct way?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to angular JS. Now I am creating an application using AngularJS + Codeigniter. I understand the basic concepts of AngularJS. I have done the basic operations like Add, View, Update, Delete records from database. Now I have several doubts.

Normally we fetch the database initially into a scope variable. All the listing is done using this JSON data. If we update a record using $http request the changes affect our database. But it does not change the data in the scope. Ideas to solve this

1. Made a request to the server to update the scope variable.
2. Just update the scope variable also along with the updating the database.

Which method should I follow?

Comment: i would definitely not go with method 2. when you make a call with $http there is a callback you can use to update the scope - either return the result when the call succeeds or make another call to update the scope.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the first method. You should use another request to update the scope data. Using this approach the scope data will always be up to date with the data stored in the database. Also you have to think about what will happen if the database raises some error. If you use the second method the scope data will be temporary updated, but after refreshing the page the new changes will be lost, because nothing is stored in the database.